# Bitnami + Redmine + Git Not Working

Tags: git, redmine, bitnami, osx-server

After a lot of failed attempts using Rails to install Redmine on OS 10.6 Server, I finally found away to do it using the [**Bitnami Rubystack**](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) + Redmine module.

Now redmine is up and running, I've hit another hurdle with Git integration. I can't get Redmine to integrate with Git **at all**.

Using rubyconsole in Rubystack, I followed the [Git specific instructions about creating a bare repository.](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories)

Still, when I try adding the repository to a project in Redmine, I see a 404 warning when I click on the main **Repository** tab:

> 404 - The entry or revision was not
>   found in the repository.

and when I click on the **Settings > Repository > Users** icon, I get:

> Select or update the Redmine user
>   mapped to each username found in the
>   repository log.   Users with the same
>   Redmine and repository username or
>   email are automatically mapped.

The username & email I am using for the Redmine account is the same as for the git account.

All the other questions on stack overflow and the web I've found are from people who have already gotten past this step and have successfully linked a git repository to Redmine. Can anybody offer any advice?

Comment: Is your "Path to `.git` directory" correct, as in "`/var/redmine/git_repositories/donebox.git/`" ?

Comment: It's installed on top of rubystack so redmine sits inside an apps folder. There is no var folder. I set the path to:
/apps/redmine/git_repositories/donebox.git/
I even tried this too (out of desperation):
/Applications/rubystack-2.2-0/apps/redmine/git_repositories/donebox.git/

Comment: The `var` folder is not important (it was just an example). Only the exact full path to a `.git` directory. If you can make an '`ls`' of that *full* path from a shell, it should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Hello although this might be a bit late I found a workaround for this exact problem.
Basicly I symlinked the "apps/gitorious/repositories" directory from the bitnamy gitorious-stack to "apps/redmine/repositories"

```
cd /opt/redmine-2.0.3-1/apps/redmine
ln -s /opt/gitorious-20120621-0/apps/gitorious/repositories
```

Aditionally I added a default ACL entry to the repositories directory allowing others to read and execute everything in there

```
setfacl -R -m d:o:rx /opt/gitorious-20120621-0/apps/gitorious/repositories
```

Finally I added the git repository in redmine with the following path:

```
/opt/redmine-2.0.3-1/apps/redmine/repositories/myrepo/myrepo.git
```

This sure ain't a beautiful way to do it.

I'm still investigating why the redmine stack can't access the repository directly though.

Comment: The accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000247/redmine-gitolite-issue-with-repository-permissions-and-more helped me get direct access to the git repository working. Using gitolite, so may be different.