# git push with error message

Tags: git, gitolite

I have gitolite on server with next config

```
@developers = john bill 

repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   admin

repo    main-project
        RW+CD      =   admin
        R master$       =  @developers
        RW+ develop$    =  @developers
```

and all `@developers` can see next error message, when they do `git push`

```
$ git push origin develop
Counting objects: 117, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
Writing objects: 100% (93/93), 400.94 KiB
Total 93 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: Unable to append to ./logs/HEAD: P
To ssh://gitolite@server/project
   ed683c3..b27b683  develop -> develop
```

how could I solve it ?

Comment: did you check the permissions and owner for the file `.git/logs/HEAD`?

Comment: @niculare localy or remotely ???

Comment: since the problem arises when you push, I suspect there's a problem remotely.

Comment: @niculare you are right, I've tried to change owner but after push permissions going away again :(

Comment: @niculare what permissions should be in all files/folders inside `/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/main-project.git` folder ?

Comment: there should be `execute` permission on all files. Also change the owner if it is `root`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try, tomorrow will make new push. Permission is changed already. Than you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Error-Unable-to-append-to-logs-HEAD-Permission-denied-td5063068.html) mentions the possibility for that "`Unable to append to ./logs/HEAD`" error message to come from the shared nature of the remote repo.
Shared meaning being accessed by different user ids, not just by different people using the same git-account.

In that case:

- setting `core.sharedRepository` to `true` in the git local config of that repo (the bare repo on the gitolite server) will help,
- as well as fixing-up permissions manually at least on `logs/HEAD`: the thread mentions "all files & dirs under `${repo}.git` should be owned by the group and `+rw` for the group", but that might not be a good example.
  See a more complete example at "[Redmine + Gitolite - Issue with repository permissions and more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086803/6309)".