# Gitweb not displaying some repos

Tags: git, permissions, repository, gitolite, gitweb

I am trying to use Gitolite + Gitweb but I am running into some problems..

My `conf/gitolite.conf` is the following

```
@dataset_repos      = dat1 dat2
@closedsrc_repos    = cod1 cod2 
@opensrc_repos      = testing

@admins             = user1 user2
@bios               = user1 user2 user3
@coders             = user1 user3

repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   @admins

repo @opensrc_repos
    RW+     =   @all

repo @dataset_repos
    RW+     =   @admins @bios 

repo @closedsrc_repos
    RW+     =   @admins @coders
```

When I first inserted repository code1 and code2, git told me:

```
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/code1.git/
remote: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/repositories/code2.git/
```

I did an initial commit on code2 but it didn't show up.
So I checked the permission and I found that these were:

```
drwxrwx--- 8 git git 4096 Oct  1 18:58 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 git git 4096 Oct  1 19:08 ../
drwxrwx--- 8 git git 4096 Oct  1 19:08 gitolite-admin.git/
drwxrws--- 7 git git 4096 Oct  1 17:15 dat1.git/
drwx------ 7 git git 4096 Oct  1 18:58 code1.git/
drwx------ 7 git git 4096 Oct  1 18:58 code2.git/
drwxrwx--- 7 git git 4096 Sep 30 18:20 testing.git/
drwxrws--- 7 git git 4096 Oct  1 17:15 dat2.git/
```

So I fixed permission for repo `code1.git` and `code2.git` with:

```
# Fix ownership
sudo chown -R git:git *

# Fix directory permissions
sudo find <repo.git> -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;

# Fix file permissions
sudo find <repo.git> -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

The two repos showed up on gitweb interface. 
However, `gl-conf` for each of these two repos was not generated.
Now, doing a commit, permissions are messed up again, and repos are not showing..

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000247/redmine-gitolite-issue-with-repository-permissions-and-more) I PARTIALLY solved it like this:

1. Initially, gitweb doesn't have any permissions to read the repository, so we fix the problem by adding the gitweb user (usually `www-data` or `apache`) to the git group by running `usermod -a -G git www-data` (be aware of your server's configuration, because that can be a little different, according to how you configurated `gitolite`.
2. Change the `UMASK` property on the `.gitolite.rc` file (present in git user home directory), from the default value of `0077` to `0022`, the equivalent of `755 (rwxr-xr-x)` for directories and `644 (rw-r--r--)` for files.
3. For existing repos, you might need to run a `chmod -R g+rX`

More infos on link above.

Anyway, every time I edit `gitolite-admin` repo, this shows up in the list of present repositories.. How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

also, if rights are ok, you should check which dir is scan for gitweb and where put gitolite repos, it can be different and symlinks makes new repos visible.